# Traverse expression tree not in reverse order c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, expression

I'm trying to traverse properties names via expression. Have code below:

```
public class Traveler
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
}

public class Ticket
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

public void Test()
{
    Expression<Func<Traveler, string>> expr = traveler => traveler.Ticket.Number;

    var visitor = new PropExpressionVisitor();
    visitor.Visit(expr);
}

public class PropExpressionVisitor: ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.Member.Name);

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

I expect console to print: 
Ticket 
Number 
**But it seems like Expression Visitor traverses in reverse order and prints:** 
Number 
Ticket 
From sources on Expression tree, I understand it should parse from root node all the way down. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Move the Console.WriteLine after the base.VisitMember

Comment: @CSharpie Is there any docs on why it traverses expression tree from the very child? BWT can you post your answer again, I'll mark it as the right one. Thank you

Comment: Well not exactly sure, but this is more a fundamental understanding of how trees work, than it is special to expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move the `Console.WriteLine` below the base method call

```
public class PropExpressionVisitor: ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        var expression = base.VisitMember(node);
        
        Console.WriteLine(node.Member.Name);
        
        return expression;
    }
}
```